# Unable to change volume in command prompt

Tags: command-line

I am unable to change my volume using `cd d:` in command prompt using administrator rights. After typing this it just reopens `c drive` for me instead of opening `d drive`.

**Edit**

I came to a little solution that open the `d drive` using `cd /d d:` command but it is unable to open the `e drive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows, to change volumes you use

```
D:
```

to switch to the D drive, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 D:
```

To switch volumes. No need for the CD command